# C# Mono Process input error

Tags: c#, shell, process, mono

Hello fellow StackOverflow users. I am trying to write some code that opens a new console/terminal window, starts GnuPlot, executing the `gnuplot` command, and then plots the sine function, using `plot sin(x)`.

Note that it only prints that if you run it inside the `gnuplot` command. The GnuPlot program is kind of a Python shell, if you didn't get the picture yet.

## The Problem

I can get it to execute `gnuplot` just nice, it runs the command on the **current** window (*not the problem of this question, but feel free to solve it!)* but it does not recognizes `plot sin(x)` as a command. My guess is that it executes `gnuplot` and somehow exits the GnuPlot shell and go back to the normal console mode.

**Note**: I am using KUbuntu 16.04 LTS.

## The Code

```
public void Plot() {
        // GetCommand() always returns "gnuplot" for now.

        ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash", String.Format("-c {0};plot sin(x)", GetCommand())) {
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        }; 

        Process process = new Process () { StartInfo = pInfo };

        process.Start ();
    }
```

The console returns the error: `sin(x): plot: command not found`.

## What I have tried

To replace `; plot sin(x)` with `&& plot sin(x)`, same error is returned.

To write to the StandardInput using the line `process.StandardInput.WriteLine ("plot sin(x)");`, however it throws a **System.InvalidOperationException** informing `Standard input has not been redirected` even tought I redirected it on the ProcessStartInfo!

Answer (score 1):

You can you use a `fifo` file as the input file to `gnuplot` and then write to that file to provide `gnuplot` scripting commands.

(`man mkfifo` for details)

#### Example:

```
Process.Start("mkfifo", "/tmp/plotpipe");
var pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"/usr/local/bin/gnuplot", "/tmp/plotpipe")
{
    RedirectStandardInput = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};
var process = new Process() { StartInfo = pInfo };
process.Start();
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"/tmp/plotpipe", false))
{
    file.Write("print sum [i=1:10] i");
}
Process.Start("rm", "/tmp/plotpipe");
```

#### Output:

```
55.0

Press any key to continue...
```